# Bypassing firewall and exploit the target

Tags: firewalls, vulnerability, antivirus, metasploit, windows-server

I have a victim which is vulnerable to the RPC-DCOM vulnerability (MS03_26).
The victim OS is Windows Server 2003, and It has Kaspersky Antivirus. When I try to exploit via Metasploit it exploited completely but no session will be created.

Answer (score 1):

This is because that vulnerability is patched. You can practice on Windows Server 2000

Before exploiting, first find information related to that vulnerability

`msf> info exploit/windows/smb/ms03_26`

Also when you set your exploit then use the command `check`

It will tell you if the vulnerability exists in victim or not

Comment: @Behdad your outburst was unwarranted and misguided. Please be nice.